# Pausing and resuming a sequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The yield function in Kotlin states the following:

> Yields a value to the Iterator being built and suspends until the next
>   value is requested.

In the following Kotlin code:

```
val sequence = sequence {
    val start = 0
    // yielding a single value
    yield(start)
    // yielding an iterable
    yieldAll(1..5 step 2)
    // yielding an infinite sequence
    yieldAll(generateSequence(8) { it * 3 })
}
```

The yield statement is inside the sequence function. What I would like to do is have a Pause button that prevents further sequence items from being processed and a Resume button that when pressed allows the processing of the next item in the sequence. However if yield is inside of the sequence function, it isn't clear how a Pause/Resume flag can be used with this.

Comment: Can you provide a use case for these `Pause` and `Resume` buttons? It is not clear what you want.

Comment: Suppose I have a collection of 100 items that need to be processed and the total time to process all of them is several minutes. The user may want to pause processing the collection and then at a later date resume processing. This really could be anything, such as running tests, processing graphics, etc.. rxJava is good at allowing you to process collections and you can use onNext after a pause to continue. But I'm wondering how to do this without rxJava, using just a Kotlin sequence. I was thinking that maybe it might be possible to call Kotlin's yield conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Sequences are just iterator suppliers, and iterators should be able to provide all elements without pauses:

```
for (elm in iterator) { }
// all elements must be created at this moment
// no additional elements allowed
```

Iterator can start sleeping during the next element providing. But, in this case, the caller thread (coroutine) will be blocked (suspended).

I assume you don't want to block threads, so I suggest creating a higher-order function that works like `launch` but returns `Pauseable` instead of `Job`:

```
fun CoroutineScope.launchPausable(block: suspend PauseableScope.() -> Unit): Pauseable =
    PauseableCoroutine(this, block)

interface PauseableScope {
    suspend fun pausePoint()
}

interface Pauseable {
    fun pause()
    fun resume()
    val job: Job
}

class PauseableCoroutine(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    block: suspend PauseableScope.() -> Unit
) : Pauseable, PauseableScope {
    private var continuation: Continuation<Unit>? = null
    private var isPaused = false
    override val job = scope.launch { block() }

    override fun pause() {
        isPaused = true
    }

    override fun resume() {
        syncIf({ isPaused }) {
            isPaused = false
            continuation?.resume(Unit)
            continuation = null
        }
    }

    override suspend fun pausePoint() {
        suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn<Unit> { cont ->
            syncIf({ isPaused }) {
                continuation = cont
                COROUTINE_SUSPENDED
            } ?: Unit
        }
    }
}
```

Where `syncIf` is simple [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) function:

```
inline fun <R> Any.syncIf(
    crossinline condition: () -> Boolean,
    crossinline block: () -> R
): R? {
    if (condition())
        synchronized(this) {
            if (condition()) return block()
        }
    return null
}
```

Use case:

```
val pausable = GlobalScope.launchPausable {
    items.forEach { item ->
        doSomething(item)
        // If it is paused coroutine will get suspended
        pausePoint()
    }
}
pausable.pause()
pausable.resume()
```

You can also put `pausePoint()` inside `doSomething(item)`:

```
suspend fun PauseableScope.doSomething(item: Item) {
    delay(100)
    pausePoint()
    delay(100)
}
```